# Meteor: Iron.Router Catch All (Will match the rest of the URI)

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Is it possible to define a Iron.Router route with a parameter that will match the rest of the URI?

For example

```
Router.route('results', {
    path: '/test/:domain'
});
```

This will match on entries like

- /test/**hello**
- /test/**hello.com**

What I really need, is to also match on entries such as

- /test/**hello.com/about**
- /test/**hello.com/about?param=3**

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how!

In this case the path will now be

```
Router.route('results', {
    path: '/test/(.*)'
});
```

To access the trailing info, access the parameter at index 0

```
this.params[0]
```